# What is the /config file in the android root directory used for?

Tags: file-system

In the `/` directory of an android device is a file called config what is this file used for?

I am assuming it is used for configuration files and other things but my Google searching has not been able to turn up anything useful.

When I look in the file (on rooted device), it is empty!

Are the files hidden? Or is there nothing there? thanks

Comment: Are you referring to `default.prop`?